# Counting special text of children in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have this xml document :

```
    <AAA> 
      <CCC> 
           <BBB>SALAM</BBB>
           <BBB>HALET KHUBE</BBB> 
           <BBB>HEY</BBB> 
           <TTT>SALAM</TTT>
           <GGG/>
           <ZZZ/>
      </CCC> 
      <DDD> 
           <BBB>GOOD</BBB> 
           <BBB>BOOO</BBB> 
           <GGG/>
           <GGG/>
           <ZZZ/>
      </DDD> 
      <EEE> 
           <CCC>TAKE</CCC> 
           <DDD>LEAVE</DDD>
           <ZZZ/>
           <ZZZ/>
           <ZZZ/> 
      </EEE> 
 </AAA>
```

I want to select nodes that  have 2 children with text = "SALAM" ( that node can have any number of children but it must have 2 chidren with text = "SALAM") .For example in above xml ,the xpath query must return CCC tag.
please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[count(*[text() = 'SALAM']) = 2 ]
```

**It may be more efficient to use the following**:

```
/*/*
  [*[text() = 'SALAM'][2]
 and
   not([*[text() = 'SALAM'][3])
  ]
```

**Always when possible try to avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator**, because in many cases it can be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `count()` xpath function:

```
//*[count(./*[text()="SALAM"])=2]
```